# How to move backgrounds in Corona SDK?

Tags: image, background, sdk, lua, coronasdk

I need any idea about how move around the background. I have a big background and I need move for it.

Example:

I have:

```
background = display.newImage ("background.png") 
function -- ( for touch )
   --here need how move around the background.
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to the [transition](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/transition/to.html) class.

Example:

```
local image = display.newImage("your_image_here.png")
image.x, image.y = some_position_x, some_position_y
transition.moveBy(image, {x=300, time=1000})
```

Comment: thanks friend, this i can move to left the image.. now only need move in all x / y coordinates for move in all background

Answer (score 1):

You can learn how to move an image from the Docs, check the sample code here:

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImage.html